# How to set a mass of mesh of an actor (Blueprint or C++)?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm creating an actor that has a static mesh component. I want to acess that static mesh mass and override it to a variable. I've tried Set All Mass Scale, Set Mass Scale, Set Mass Override. In the last two it asks for a bone name, which I don't understand as I work with a static mesh not a skeletal mesh. None of three seem to do anything. How to set a mesh mass inside of an actor class (preferrably in the costructor) in UE5/4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example from [here](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/physics-mass-override/277555/3):

```
void AYourStaticMeshActorClass::SetMassScale(const float& NewScale)
{
    if(!StaticMeshComponent) return;
       //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    FBodyInstance* BodyInst = StaticMeshComponent->GetBodyInstance();

    if(!BodyInst) return;
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    // New Scale 
    BodyInst->MassScale = NewScale;  

    // Trigger Update! 
    BodyInst->UpdateMassProperties();
}
```